# get name of an object inside a loop

Tags: r

I know the deparse+substitute trick to get the name from an object passed as argument to a function, but the same trick inside a loop does no work.

My code (just for testing):

```
mylist <- list(first = c("lawyer","janitor"), second = c("engineer","housewife"))

for (element in names(mylist)){
  print(deparse(substitute(mylist[[element]])))
}

[1] "mylist[[element]]"
[1] "mylist[[element]]"
```

is there any way of getting the result?:

```
first
second
```

Comment: In your example you can just use `print(element)`..

Comment: What's wrong with `names(mylist)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "names"

```
for (element in names(mylist)){
  print(as.name(element))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using `lapply`

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) { print(names(x))} )
# NULL
# NULL
# $first
# NULL
# 
# $second
# NULL
```

using `for` loop as per your question

```
for (element in names(mylist)){
  print(element)
}
# [1] "first"
# [1] "second"
```

Comment: The lapply is doing something slightly different, since it applies the `names` function to each list element, returning NULL because they don't have names in the example.